# Clear-down UGC databases

Tags: 2011, database, ugc

After some initial tests to make sure everything was OK with a UGC installation I want to clear down all test comments/rating/stats before we hand it over.

Is there a "supported" way to does this quickly - rather than finding each comment within the Tridion GUI and deleting it (which wouldn't help with ratings anyway).

I'd like to simply run an few SQL DELETE statements against each table but just wanted to check if there was any reason why I shouldn't.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be easier to use the installation scripts to generate a new UGC database and simply drop (backing up first of course :)) the old db all together?

Comment: Nice bit of lateral thinking John! This is 2011 SP1 HR1 so I guess you mean re-run the TDM to create a new db?

Comment: The DB create scripts are also available for 2011 SP1, in the scripts folder of the installer.